# IONIC 4 fixed slot below scrolling grid on iOS not working

Tags: css, ionic-framework, scroll, ionic4

I am trying to show a fixed slot div below scrolling grid with `z-index` and `position: relative`. It works in Chrome and on Android, however not on iOS. I have seen recommendations to use `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)`, however this does not help.

Is there a reliable solution?

Using default IONIC tabs project.

```
Ionic:
Ionic CLI                     : 6.9.2 
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.10
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
@angular/cli                  : 7.3.10
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1
```

tab1.page.html:

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Tab 1
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <div class="fixed-slot" slot="fixed">
  </div>
  <ion-grid class="grid">
    <ion-row class="row"></ion-row>
    <ion-row class="row"></ion-row>
    <ion-row class="row"></ion-row>
    <ion-row class="row"></ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

tab1.page.scss:

```
.grid {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.row {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.fixed-slot {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Chrome (expected result):
[image]

iOS (not working):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `slot="fixed"` and instead style it to be `position:fixed` in your css.